# Stock Price Start and End range from specified time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, stock

I have this code that works when manually entering a start date and an end date:

```
import datetime as dt
from datetime import date
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as web

today = date.today()
style.use("ggplot")
start = dt.datetime(2020,1,1)
end = today
df = web.get_data_yahoo("TSLA", start, end)
df["Adj Close"].plot()
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.ylabel("Price $")
plt.title("TSLA Stock Price ", )
plt.show()
```

It works when plotting the graph, but I want the start and end date to show up on the title as well. Is there anyway that I can import the "start" and "end" variables after "TSLA Stock Price "?

Comment: you could use [strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) to format the dates to string...

Comment: does this actually have anything to do with stocks or just formatting dates into a plot's title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just use an f string in the plt.title().

```
plt.title(f"TSLA Stock Price {start.strftime('%x')} to {end.strftime('%x')}")
```

This code results in the title being formated like mm/dd/yy to mm/dd/yy

Comment: Thanks! It also shows the time after start (Ex: 2020-1-1 00:00:00). Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: You could use strftime which was suggested above to get rid of the time. I'll edit the above answer to reflect that.

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you!